# Need something like Accept Button in User Control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio

I need to have a `Button` on a `UserControl` (not `Form`) in a windows application to respond to "Enter" hit, the way a button which is set as the `Accept Button` of a `Form` works.

I cannot make the button to be focused, since I need other controls to be focused with tab change.

Any help is really appreciated :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The AcceptButton is a property of Form and cannot be used for the UserControl. You can simply override ProcessCmdKey though and this will work so long as the user control has focus. Otherwise you will need to use the AcceptButton of the form separately or override the ProcessCmdKey in the form if you have multiple controls which could be active.

```
  protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData) 
  {
      if (keyData == Keys.Enter) 
      {
        button.PerformClick();
        return true;
      }
      return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
```

Comment: While this works, there is a drawback with this approach. Let's say I have a user control, that has range of search criteria input boxes and a `Accept` button to trigger search. If I have some lookup fields there, then entering a phrase in that box on `Enter` I would need to first resolve that value and search should be triggered on second `Enter` (this is how this would work if this would be regular `Form` with "regular" `AcceptButton`, but with `ProcessCmdKey` I don't see a reasonable way to make it resolve lookup value first and search only if that search parameter is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the Modifier property on the button to "Public", you can use the button as AcceptButton on the form. Unfortunately you cannot do it design-time with the properties window of Visual Studio, but you can do it in code.

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.AcceptButton = userControl11.button1;
    }
```

Comment: Original poster explicitly asked this for a UserControl (**not Form**) which does not have an `AcceptButton` property.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, and already answered, however I use this in some situations:

```
private void UserControl11_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.FindForm().AcceptButton = Button1;
}
```