# Get Focus / maintain Selected a TextBox and a Button | C#

Tags: c#, forms, select, button, focus

Im trying to get the focus like this picture:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkMtH.png]

-

So I can have a selected TextBox and Write to it while having aswell the Focus on the Accept button

```
    private void frm_redimensionar_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (frm_MonoPaint.Exporto == " ")
        {
            num_amplada.Value = 32;
            num_alcada.Value = 32;
        }
        num_amplada.Focus(); //
        bttn_enviar.Focus(); // 
    }
    private void bttn_cancelar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }
    private void bttn_enviar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        Close();
    }
    public int redAlcada()
    {
        return Convert.ToInt32(num_alcada.Value);
    }
    public int redAmplada()
    {
        return Convert.ToInt32(num_amplada.Value);
    }
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        if (keyData == Keys.Escape)
        {
            this.Close();
            return true;
        }
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
```

Comment: you need to show us what you have done in code, are you using the `SaveDialog` if so show us what you have tried..

Comment: Its just a new Form with a textbox and a button that returns OK

Comment: there are examples on the web in regards to filters etc.. do a google search on C# SaveDialog

Comment: Wait, so it this not even related to the .NET SaveDialog and you just want to have a TextBox with focus and a default button? That's pretty simple stuff...

Comment: Ye, its simple but im like 2 days searching 4 it and i still dont have any idea

- just a newbie

Comment: I'll give you a hint: You might find the AcceptButton form property handy, and also, classes that extend from Control (TextBoxes included) have a Focus method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need something like Accept Button in User Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19512814/need-something-like-accept-button-in-user-control)

Comment: @DangerZone seached some stuff over my project, still blank idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i found the answer to my own question.

```
 ""this."" AcceptButton = yourbuttonname;
```

Was a bad title for this post but when you dont know what ur doing it happens. .-.